How to merge the two PR's at one time in Azure Devops
I have two PR's PR-A and PR-B two different repos and two are interdependent
I need to merge these two pr's only after PR-A and PR-B are completed/build successfully.
The problem is that PR-A must not be merged until PR-B is ready to be merged as well, and vice versa.

There is no method to satisfy you demands. Actually, your demands are almost not possible to be met.

Checking the settings on the web UI of Azure DevOps, no option to lock a PR to disallow users complete it.

Checking the Azure DevOps REST API and Azure DevOps CLI, also no API/CLI to lock PR.



Create a Coordination Pipeline:
Create a new pipeline in one of the repositories (or a separate coordination repository) that will coordinate the merging of PR-A and PR-B.
This pipeline will check the status of both PRs and only proceed if both builds are successful.

is this something will provide a solution

@Saikumar, I don't think this is a good solution. This method cannot disallow users to manually complete the PR or when the PR has auto-complete set. As long as all the required checks and approvals have been passed on a PR, this PR can be completed at any time by manual or auto-complete.

@Saikumar, Are above clarification and explanation helpful for you to understand deeper?
